# Zend Form action="#" not working

Tags: zend-framework, hosting, shared-hosting

Ive been working on a project on my local machine and recently purchased a shared hosting account with ServerGrove(php5.3). After uploading my project all of my form submissions are broken.  On my local host all of my forms submit to the current action, .  This has been working fine.  It even works on my godaddy and hostgator hosting packages.  However the forms wont submit, they just reload on submit.  Any ideas?

#### Rewrite Rules

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Sounds like your POSTs are getting re-written as GETs. Post your rewrite rules

Comment: Phil, thanks for you help.  I was playing around with my .htaccess earlier to reqrite to a subdirectory, but was having issues getting it to work so I deleted it.  Is it possible that what I was doing earlier is cached?

Comment: You deleted your `.htaccess` file or just the bits you added?

Comment: the files, I only have one .htaccess now which is located in my public directory which is posted above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `die(var_dump($_POST));` on the first line of controller you expect the form to be submited to. You can also use FireBug to find any redirects that will make the server "forget" the POST.